# Trying to connect to "ELlight" branded light strip via python to change colors

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, led

So I have been tasked with connecting to a strand of lights bought off amazon. These lights can be discovered by bluetooth and are controlled by an app available on the play store and app store. Upon further discovery I found out it's using a sp110e controller using a ble driver. I have this code to get characteristics:

`

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

async def run(address, loop):
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
        # Get a list of all the services and characteristics exposed by the BLE device
        services = await client.get_services()
        for service in services:
            print("Service: {0} ({1})".format(service.uuid, service.description))
            for characteristic in service.characteristics:
                print("Characteristic: {0} ({1})".format(characteristic.uuid, characteristic.description))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run("75:57:08:05:95:E3", loop))
```

`

and get this result :

```
Service: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Generic Access Profile)
Characteristic: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Device Name)
Characteristic: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Appearance)
Characteristic: 00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Peripheral Privacy Flag)
Characteristic: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters)
Service: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Generic Attribute Profile)
Service: 0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Vendor specific)
Characteristic: 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Vendor specific
```

This was the script to change colors:

`

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

async def run(address, loop):
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
        # Convert the RGB color (255, 0, 0) to hexadecimal (FF0000)
        r = 0
        g = 255
        b = 0
        #hex_color = "{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}".format(r, g, b)
        hex_color = "00FF00"
        # Convert the hexadecimal color to bytes
        color_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hex_color)

        # Set the color of the lights
        await client.write_gatt_char("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", color_bytes)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run("75:57:08:05:95:E3", loop))

This was the error I got
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 402, in connect
    _, pending = await asyncio.wait(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 418, in wait
    return await _wait(fs, timeout, return_when, loop)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 525, in _wait
    await waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occured:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gdelgado/Documents/Testing to change the color to red.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(run("75:57:08:05:95:E3", loop))
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/Users/gdelgado/Documents/Testing to change the color to red.py", line 5, in run
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 433, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 471, in connect
    return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 389, in connect
    async with async_timeout.timeout(timeout):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\async_timeout\__init__.py", line 129, in __aexit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\async_timeout\__init__.py", line 212, in _do_exit
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError
TimeoutError
```

I ran the above color changing but seem to have hit a wall. The code was suppose to turn the lights green

Comment: How confident are you that the value of `00FF00` should change the lights green? Have you been able to change the light colours from a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration app like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)? As the attribute is vendor specific it would be good to confirm the value being sent is correct before focusing on the Python code.

Comment: 0xFF-01-53-00-FF-00-03-02-58-FA-E1-E1-00 is the value I got when using the app recommended uuid is ffe1. When changing values from 0xFF-01-53-00-FF-00-03-02-58-FA-E1-E1-00 to 0xFF-01-42-00-FF-00-03-02-04-FA-E1-E1-00 it would not allow me to hit write in the nRF app

Comment: What permissions does the `fee1`. Is it `write` and `notify`?  Is there an `ffe2`